# bottle request.forms.get returns None

Tags: python, html, get, bottle

I am trying to send information from a web form into python using bottle.  I am using get to send a variable "test" but when i call the request function for "test", it returns none.  I've been using the [bottle tutorial](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#http-request-methods) as my reference.

Here is my web form:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/page" method="get">
<input type="number" name="test" step="5">
<input type="submit" name="my-form" value="GO">
</form>
```

If you type 1 in the field and click go, this brings you to the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/page?test=10&my-form=GO
```

And here is the bottle python code:

```
@route('/page', method='GET')
def index():
testvar = request.forms.get('test')
return 'Hello %s' % testvar
```

From what I understand, request.forms.get('test') should retrieve the value from test=10 in the url and pass it into testvar.  However, I receive a value of none, meaning the var is empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.forms), `request.forms` will only collect the POST and PUT parameters:

> **forms**
>
> Form values parsed from an url-encoded or
>   multipart/form-data encoded POST or PUT request body. The result is
>   returned as a FormsDict. All keys and values are strings.

In your case, you have the `HTTP` `GET` form, use [`request.params`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.params).

Comment: Thanks!  .params worked.  Ask mentions in another answer above, .query worked as well.

Comment: @NathanWittich yeah, we've posted answers almost at the same time. Accept any answer you like. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are doing a HTTP GET, the parameters are not passed as a form but as query parameters. Bottle provides [`request.query`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.query) to access these parameters:

> The query_string parsed into a FormsDict. These values are sometimes called “URL arguments” or “GET parameters”, but not to be confused with “URL wildcards” as they are provided by the Router.

The [`request.forms`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.forms) is to be used for a HTTP POST:

> Form values parsed from an url-encoded or multipart/form-data encoded POST or PUT request body. The result is returned as a FormsDict. All keys and values are strings. File uploads are stored separately in files.

Comment: Thanks!  .query worked.  Ask mentions in another answer below, .params worked as well.